# Некорректно работает бот (python-telegram-bot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, бот, python-telegram-bot

Создала бота используя python-telegram-bot. Вот код:

```
import os
import time
import sys

import logging
from telegram import Update, ReplyKeyboardRemove, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, CommandHandler, Filters, CallbackContext, CallbackQueryHandler, ConversationHandler
from telegram.ext.dispatcher import run_async

TOKEN = ''

log = get_logger(__file__)

def facts_to_str(user_data):
    facts = list()
    for key, value in user_data.items():
        facts.append('{} - {}'.format(key, value))
    return "\n".join(facts).join(['\n', '\n'])

user_dict = {}

@run_async
@log_func(log)
def start(update, context):
    user_id = update.message.from_user.id
    print('User ID: {} '.format(user_id))

    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("О мастере ", callback_data='master'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton("Контакты ☎️", callback_data='contacts'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton("Виды массажа", callback_data='types_massage')],
                [InlineKeyboardButton("Записаться‍", callback_data='sing_up'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton("Отменить запись", callback_data='cancel')]]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    update.message.reply_text('''Здравствуйте! 
Я личный помощник Вашего мастера.
C моей помощью Вы можете узнать о видах массажа, записаться на сеанс или отменить свою запись.
С чего начнём? ⬇️''', reply_markup=reply_markup)

@run_async
@log_func(log)
def sing(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("Классический", callback_data='klass'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton("Лечебный", callback_data='lech'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton("Медовый", callback_data='med')],
                [InlineKeyboardButton("Лимфодренажный", callback_data='limfo'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton("Антицеллюлитный", callback_data='anti')],
                [InlineKeyboardButton(" Главное меню", callback_data='home')]]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    query.edit_message_text(text='Выберите вид массажа: ⬇️', reply_markup=reply_markup)

@run_async
@log_func(log)
def klassik(update, context):
    user_data = context.user_data
    category = 'Вид массажа'
    massage = 'Классический'
    user_data[category] = massage

    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    query.edit_message_text("Выберите дату: ", reply_markup=telegramcalendar.create_calendar())

@run_async
@log_func(log)
def lechebny(update, context):
    user_data = context.user_data
    category = 'Вид массажа'
    massage = 'Лечебный'
    user_data[category] = massage
    
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    query.edit_message_text("Выберите дату: ", reply_markup=telegramcalendar.create_calendar())

@run_async
@log_func(log)
def medovy(update, context):
    user_data = context.user_data
    category = 'Вид массажа'
    massage = 'Медовый'
    user_data[category] = massage

    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    query.edit_message_text("Выберите дату: ", reply_markup=telegramcalendar.create_calendar())

@run_async
@log_func(log)
def limfo(update, context):
    user_data = context.user_data
    category = 'Вид массажа'
    massage = 'Лимфодренажный'
    user_data[category] = massage

    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    query.edit_message_text("Выберите дату: ", reply_markup=telegramcalendar.create_calendar())

@run_async
@log_func(log)
def anti(update, context):
    user_data = context.user_data
    category = 'Вид массажа'
    massage = 'Антицеллюлитный'
    user_data[category] = massage

    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    
    query.edit_message_text("Выберите дату: ", reply_markup=telegramcalendar.create_calendar())

@run_async
@log_func(log)
def select(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    bot = context.bot

    selected, date = telegramcalendar.process_calendar_selection(bot, update)
    if selected:
        user_data = context.user_data
        category = 'Дата'
        text = date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        user_data[category] = text
        
        keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("12:00", callback_data='12'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("14:30", callback_data='14'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("16:00", callback_data='16')]]

        reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

        query.message.reply_text(text='''Вы выбрали %s
Выберите свободное время: ''' % (date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")), reply_markup=reply_markup)

@run_async
@log_func(log)
def time_12(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    user_data = context.user_data
    category = 'Время'
    text = '12:00'
    user_data[category] = text

    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    query.edit_message_text('''Введите своё *Имя и Фамилию*''', parse_mode='Markdown')

@run_async
@log_func(log)
def time_14(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    user_data = context.user_data
    category = 'Время'
    text = '14:30'
    user_data[category] = text

    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    query.edit_message_text('''Введите своё *Имя и Фамилию*''', parse_mode='Markdown')

@run_async
@log_func(log)
def time_16(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    user_data = context.user_data
    category = 'Время'
    text = '16:00'
    user_data[category] = text

    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    query.edit_message_text('''Введите своё *Имя и Фамилию*''', parse_mode='Markdown')

@run_async
@log_func(log)
def sing_name(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    global user_name
    user_data = context.user_data
    category = 'Имя Фамилия'
    user_name = update.message.text
    user_data[category] = user_name
    print('Сохранено имя: ' + user_name)

    contact_keyboard = KeyboardButton('Отправить номер', request_contact=True)
    custom_keyboard = [[contact_keyboard]]
    markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(custom_keyboard, resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)

    update.message.reply_text('''*Введите свой номер телефона*''', parse_mode='Markdown', reply_markup=markup)

@run_async
@log_func(log)
def sing_contact(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    global phone
    user_data = context.user_data
    category = 'Телефон'
    phone = update.message.text or update.message.contact.phone_number
    user_data[category] = phone
    print('Сохранен номер: ' + phone)

    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("Подтвердить", callback_data='okay'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton("Изменить запись", callback_data='recording')]]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    update.message.reply_text('''*Вы зарегестрированы!*

_Ваши данные:_ 
{}'''.format(facts_to_str(user_data)), parse_mode='Markdown', reply_markup=reply_markup)

@run_async
@log_func(log)
def okay(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    query.edit_message_text('''*Спасибо за регестрацию!*

Мастер будет ожидать Вас.''', parse_mode='Markdown')

@run_async
@log_func(log)
def recording(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    sing(update, context)

def error(update, context):
    """Log Errors caused by Updates."""
    logger.warning('Update "%s" caused error "%s"', update, context.error)

def main():
    # Create the EventHandler and pass it your bot's token.
    updater = Updater(
        token=TOKEN,
        use_context=True
    )

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(sing, pattern='sing_up'))
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(klassik, pattern='klass'))
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(lechebny, pattern='lech'))
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(medovy, pattern='med'))
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(limfo, pattern='limfo'))
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(anti, pattern='anti'))
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(time_12, pattern='12'))
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(time_14, pattern='14'))
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(time_16, pattern='16'))
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(okay, pattern='okay'))
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(recording, pattern='recording'))
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(select))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, sing_name))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text | Filters.contact, sing_contact))
    
    dp.add_error_handler(error)

    updater.start_polling()

    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Проблема заключается в том, что когда пользователь доходит до функции sing_contact, у него есть два варианта: ввести свой номер вручную или оставить с помощью кнопки. Когда пользователь оставляет номер с помощью кнопки, всё работает и сохраняется корректно. Но если решат ввести номер вручную то, почему-то, срабатывает функция sing_name и номер сохраняется как Имя и Фамилия пользователя.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взял за основу код этого вопроса и вашего [предыдущего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1174642/201445).

Не работал с сложными `ConversationHandler`, поэтому были шероховатости. Рекомендую поразбираться с [примером сложных меню из библиотеки](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/2789fd2bffe761e362c8dd115254b7c730fb9e35/examples/nestedconversationbot.py#L280) (*сам хочу на днях выделить время и поразбираться, т.к. было: сложно и много непонятных моментов*).

Порядок начала выполнения с ботом:

- `/start`
- Клик на кнопку <kbd>Записаться</kbd>

[Пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/d2937cfc195292d32d1488ee7dc1257a232a5f0d/telegram_bot_examples/massage_ConversationHandler.py):

```
import sys

from telegram import (
    Update, ReplyKeyboardRemove, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton
)
from telegram.ext import (
    Updater, MessageHandler, CommandHandler, Filters, CallbackContext, CallbackQueryHandler, ConversationHandler
)
from telegram.ext.dispatcher import run_async


from config import TOKEN
from common import get_logger, log_func

import telegramcalendar


log = get_logger(__file__)


# TODO: enum
STATE_SELECT_MASSAGE = 'STATE_SELECT_MASSAGE'
STATE_SELECT_DATE = 'STATE_SELECT_DATE'
STATE_SELECT_TIME = 'STATE_SELECT_TIME'
STATE_SELECT_USER = 'STATE_SELECT_USER'
STATE_SELECT_PHONE = 'STATE_SELECT_PHONE'
STATE_FINISH = 'STATE_FINISH'


def facts_to_str(user_data: dict) -> str:
    facts = []
    for key, value in user_data.items():
        facts.append('{} - {}'.format(key, value))
    return "\n".join(facts).join(['\n', '\n'])


@run_async
@log_func(log)
def on_main_menu(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    # Если функция вызывана из CallbackQueryHandler
    query = update.callback_query
    if query:
        query.answer()

    message = update.effective_message
    user_id = update.effective_user.id
    print('User ID: {} '.format(user_id))

    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("О мастере ", callback_data='master'),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Контакты ☎️", callback_data='contacts'),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Виды массажа", callback_data='types_massage')
        ],
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Записаться‍", callback_data='sing_up'),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Отменить запись", callback_data='cancel')
        ]
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    text = '''Здравствуйте! 
Я личный помощник Вашего мастера.
C моей помощью Вы можете узнать о видах массажа, записаться на сеанс или отменить свою запись.
С чего начнём? ⬇️'''

    if query:
        message.edit_text(text, reply_markup=reply_markup)
    else:
        message.reply_text(text, reply_markup=reply_markup)


@run_async
@log_func(log)
def on_sing_up(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Классический", callback_data='klass'),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Лечебный", callback_data='lech'),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Медовый", callback_data='med')
        ],
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Лимфодренажный", callback_data='limfo'),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Антицеллюлитный", callback_data='anti')
        ],
        [InlineKeyboardButton(" Главное меню", callback_data='main_menu')]
    ]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    query.edit_message_text(text='Выберите вид массажа: ⬇️', reply_markup=reply_markup)

    return STATE_SELECT_MASSAGE


@run_async
@log_func(log)
def on_massage_klassik(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    user_data = context.user_data
    category = 'Вид массажа'
    massage = 'Классический'
    user_data[category] = massage

    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    query.edit_message_text("Выберите дату: ", reply_markup=telegramcalendar.create_calendar())

    return STATE_SELECT_DATE


@run_async
@log_func(log)
def on_massage_lechebny(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    user_data = context.user_data
    category = 'Вид массажа'
    massage = 'Лечебный'
    user_data[category] = massage

    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    query.edit_message_text("Выберите дату: ", reply_markup=telegramcalendar.create_calendar())

    return STATE_SELECT_DATE


@run_async
@log_func(log)
def on_massage_medovy(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    user_data = context.user_data
    category = 'Вид массажа'
    massage = 'Медовый'
    user_data[category] = massage

    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    query.edit_message_text("Выберите дату: ", reply_markup=telegramcalendar.create_calendar())

    return STATE_SELECT_DATE


@run_async
@log_func(log)
def on_massage_limfo(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    user_data = context.user_data
    category = 'Вид массажа'
    massage = 'Лимфодренажный'
    user_data[category] = massage

    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    query.edit_message_text("Выберите дату: ", reply_markup=telegramcalendar.create_calendar())

    return STATE_SELECT_DATE


@run_async
@log_func(log)
def on_massage_anti(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    user_data = context.user_data
    category = 'Вид массажа'
    massage = 'Антицеллюлитный'
    user_data[category] = massage

    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    query.edit_message_text("Выберите дату: ", reply_markup=telegramcalendar.create_calendar())

    return STATE_SELECT_DATE


@run_async
@log_func(log)
def on_select_date(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    bot = context.bot

    selected, date = telegramcalendar.process_calendar_selection(bot, update)
    if not selected:
        return ConversationHandler.END

    user_data = context.user_data
    text = date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    user_data['Дата'] = text

    keyboard = [[
        InlineKeyboardButton("12:00", callback_data='12'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("14:30", callback_data='14'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("16:00", callback_data='16')
    ]]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    query.message.reply_text(text='''Вы выбрали %s
Выберите свободное время: ''' % text, reply_markup=reply_markup)

    return STATE_SELECT_TIME


@run_async
@log_func(log)
def on_time_12(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    user_data = context.user_data

    text = '12:00'
    user_data['Время'] = text

    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    query.edit_message_text('''Введите своё *Имя и Фамилию*''', parse_mode='Markdown')

    return STATE_SELECT_USER


@run_async
@log_func(log)
def on_time_14(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    user_data = context.user_data

    text = '14:30'
    user_data['Время'] = text

    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    query.edit_message_text('''Введите своё *Имя и Фамилию*''', parse_mode='Markdown')

    return STATE_SELECT_USER


@run_async
@log_func(log)
def on_time_16(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    user_data = context.user_data

    text = '16:00'
    user_data['Время'] = text

    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    query.edit_message_text('''Введите своё *Имя и Фамилию*''', parse_mode='Markdown')

    return STATE_SELECT_USER


@run_async
@log_func(log)
def on_sing_name(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    user_data = context.user_data
    category = 'Имя Фамилия'
    user_name = update.message.text
    user_data[category] = user_name
    print('Сохранено имя: ' + user_name)

    contact_keyboard = KeyboardButton('Отправить номер', request_contact=True)
    custom_keyboard = [[contact_keyboard]]
    markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(custom_keyboard, resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)

    update.message.reply_text('''*Введите свой номер телефона*''', parse_mode='Markdown', reply_markup=markup)

    return STATE_SELECT_PHONE


@run_async
@log_func(log)
def on_sing_contact(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    user_data = context.user_data
    category = 'Телефон'
    phone = update.message.text or update.message.contact.phone_number
    user_data[category] = phone
    print('Сохранен номер: ' + phone)

    keyboard = [[
        InlineKeyboardButton("Подтвердить", callback_data='okay'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("Изменить запись", callback_data='recording')
    ]]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    update.message.reply_text('''*Вы зарегистрированы!*

_Ваши данные:_ 
{}'''.format(facts_to_str(user_data)), parse_mode='Markdown', reply_markup=reply_markup)

    return STATE_FINISH


@run_async
@log_func(log)
def on_finish(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    query.edit_message_text('''*Спасибо за регистрацию!*

Мастер будет ожидать Вас.''', parse_mode='Markdown')

    return ConversationHandler.END


@run_async
@log_func(log)
def on_recording(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    return on_sing_up(update, context)


def on_error(update, context):
    """Log Errors caused by Updates."""
    log.warning('Update "%s" caused error "%s"', update, context.error)


def main():
    # Create the EventHandler and pass it your bot's token.
    updater = Updater(
        token=TOKEN,
        use_context=True
    )

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', on_main_menu))

    dp.add_handler(ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[
            CommandHandler('start', on_main_menu),
            CallbackQueryHandler(on_sing_up, pattern='sing_up')
        ],
        states={
            STATE_SELECT_MASSAGE: [
                CallbackQueryHandler(on_massage_klassik, pattern='klass'),
                CallbackQueryHandler(on_massage_lechebny, pattern='lech'),
                CallbackQueryHandler(on_massage_medovy, pattern='med'),
                CallbackQueryHandler(on_massage_limfo, pattern='limfo'),
                CallbackQueryHandler(on_massage_anti, pattern='anti'),
                CallbackQueryHandler(on_main_menu, pattern='main_menu'),
            ],

            STATE_SELECT_DATE: [
                CallbackQueryHandler(on_select_date)
            ],

            STATE_SELECT_TIME: [
                CallbackQueryHandler(on_time_12, pattern='12'),
                CallbackQueryHandler(on_time_14, pattern='14'),
                CallbackQueryHandler(on_time_16, pattern='16')
            ],

            STATE_SELECT_USER: [
                MessageHandler(Filters.text, on_sing_name)
            ],

            STATE_SELECT_PHONE: [
                MessageHandler(Filters.text | Filters.contact, on_sing_contact)
            ],

            STATE_FINISH: [
                CallbackQueryHandler(on_finish, pattern='okay'),
                CallbackQueryHandler(on_recording, pattern='recording')
            ]
        },
        fallbacks=[

        ],
        # allow_reentry=True,
        # per_message=True,
    ))

    dp.add_error_handler(on_error)

    updater.start_polling()

    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Всё отлично работает, спасибо большое за помощь!)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы попроще - все команды обрабатываются сверху вниз. Т.е. `sing_name` и `sing_contact` обрабатывают одни и те же аргументы, но именно текст из сообщения обрабатывает первой sing_name. Используйте декораторы или проверяйте ввод на соответствие только цифрам (или в каком формате вы запрашиваете номер).
Конкретные строки в вашем коде:

```
def sing_name(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    ...
    user_name = update.message.text

def sing_contact(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    ...
    phone = update.message.text or update.message.contact.phone_number
```

---

**UPDATE**. *По мотивам информации в комментариях*

Нужны изменения в хендлерах:

```
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, sing_name))
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text | Filters.contact, sing_contact))
```

Первый перехватывает все текстовые сообщения, так что лучше добавить проверку на ввод цифр во второй и поменять их местами, чтобы второй обрабатывался раньше

Comment: Добавила проверку ввода на соответствие только цифрам, но всё работает без изменений. sing_name всё так же вылазит при любом пользовательском вводе.
Подскажите, как правильно внести декораторы.
Вариант `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])` выводит ошибку

Comment: На вашем месте я бы посмотрел в сторону других библиотек, таких как [aiogram](https://surik00.gitbooks.io/aiogram-lessons/content/chapter1.html)  или [pyTelegramBot](https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial/docs/pyTelegramBotAPI/lesson_00/). Здесь вам надо самой прописывать хэндлер - вот [пример из документации](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot.py)

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ! К сожалению aiogram и pyTelegramBot мне не подходят, потому что календарь написан на python-telegram-bot. Буду дальше искать пути решения)

Comment: Пожалуйста )  Удачи